# gradle plugin copy without default excludes

Tags: gradle-plugin

I want to get some dependency artifact and copy the content into a specific location.
This works well in general, but not for files called e.g. `.gitignore`.
I found that those are default excludes.

How can i disable those default exclude, by using the Java-Gradle-API in my plugin code?

```
project.copy( spec -> {
    spec.from (project.zipTree(artifact.getFile()));
    spec.into( tf.toFile());
    //spec.setExcludes(Collections.emptyList()); // does not work
});
```

Also i tried to the setExcludes in the from/into copyspec.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but i don't like it, because it modifies the globally visible defaultExcludes:

```
private static void withoutDefaultExcludes( Runnable r ) {
    String[] defaultExcludes = org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.getDefaultExcludes();
    try {
        for( String defaultExclude : defaultExcludes) {
            org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude(defaultExclude);
        }

        r.run();

    }
    finally {
        for( String defaultExclude : defaultExcludes) {
            org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.addDefaultExclude(defaultExclude);
        }
    }
}

withoutDefaultExcludes( () -> {
    project.copy( spec -> {
        spec.from (project.zipTree(artifact.getFile()));
        spec.into( tf.toFile());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe from gradle 6.3, you can edit DEFAULTEXCLUDES through `settings.gradle`.
Here is the post https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11176#issue-514473212

Worked for me with

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner

DirectoryScanner.removeDefaultExclude("**/.gitignore")
```

in `settings.gradle`